# Compute shader only updates part of data

Tags: opengl, glsl, vbo, compute-shader

I'm stuck with my program rendering all the particles, but only updating 1 particle on 3. Here's what I've done to test it. I made a vbo with 10 of my particles, put them all aligned veticaly and set the compute shader to modify their x position every update (pos.x+=0.1). Here's the result after about 1-2 seconds (image is 1:5 scale) :

[image: example]

I use local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1 and local_size_z = 1, then DispatchCompute(10,1,1) . Am I doing something wrong with the invocation ids?

## Update

Playing around with the struct definition in the shader by adding padding made it skip only one data every update. This means it's a padding problem, but I can't find any good explanation on how to properly pad. Also, is it possible not to pad? What if I don't want all this extra, useless data?

Comment: Can you post your shader and any relevant calling code. Particularly any parts to do with the padding you mention.

Comment: I just found a way, i added a vec2 pad on each struct to align them to 16 bytes and it works. Thanks anyways

Comment: Not a fun problem to work around. [Packing/unpacking](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182957-GLSL-pads-int-arrays-to-16-bytes-taking-4-times-local-memory) to fill the padding with something useful will probably be faster despite the extra code. Memory transfer is expensive.